# Help installing mythtv

Tags: mythtv

Need some help trying to install mythtv. I have installed it from the Ubuntu software center but every time i click on the mythtv back end it just gets stuck in a loop. when i try to login to mysql with mythtv it says access denied. I tried reinstalling mysql changed the password and still getting the same error. I have been fighting this for a few hours so any help would be appreciated. Also just did a fresh install if that info helps any.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run:

```
mythtv-setup
```

or if that doesn't work:

```
sudo mythtv-setup
```

and you have to set up a password or user before you can login.

Answer (score -1):

mythtv has a wiki:

[Installing MythTV on Ubuntu](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Installing_MythTV_on_Ubuntu)

I'd also recommend reading this thread from the MythTV Forum.  It covers a fresh install.

[MythTV Install Forum Thread](https://forum.mythtv.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=2757)